# How to remove the context in input reference set selector?

Tags: mendix

What I trying to do is the existing context in input reference set selector will be removed if the product has been modified. I have tried to constrained the checklist with the product. However, the context will still not be removed if I have modified the product field. May I know how to solve this?

[image]
[image]

When I modified the product, the context in the checklist field which is input reference set selector still existed.

[image]
[image]